# Android Google Sign-in doesn't work on different devices without adding SHA-1 key from each device in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've been working on an Android app with Firebase authentication via Google sign-in.

There is an issue with the Google sign-in where it doesn't allow sign-in (returns 12500 error) unless I add the SHA-1 key generated from the specific device I'm running the emulator on.

This is a problem because I have others in my team that are working on it and I have to add their device's SHA-1 key to allow them to sign in.

I've added both the SHA-1 and SHA-256 of the debug and the release key generated from my computer to the Firebase console, as well as replacing the `google-services.json` with the new one after having added the keys. (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth?utm_source=firebase.google.com&utm_medium=referral)

Also, I set the support email in the Firebase console as well because apparently that's what 12500 error is about.

But this is still only letting me sign in with Google and no one else, so I have to manually add their device's SHA-1 key each time.

With everyone's keys added, one thing odd is that my teammates are still able to sign in when they build the app to an Android phone connected to their PC and not the emulator running on the PC.

I'm sure this isn't the right way of doing things because one set of keys should be allowing sign-in to all devices.

Is there something I'm missing here?